# Youtube api get subscription video feed

Tags: c#, windows, youtube-data-api

I refer [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list).

I had succeeded to get subscription list.

I fill 2 field "part", "channel Id(my channel Id)" and Authorize requests using Aouth 20.

Now, I want to get subscriptions feed.

I had tried to request, but it's error.

I fill follow field:

"part(snippet)", "channel Id" and set "mine" & "mySubscribers" to true

why can't success, error reason is "incompatibleParameters"

BTW, I try to fill "Id" field, but I really don't know what should I fill

it's annotation say "subscribe Id". What should I fill?

Update(06/19/2015):

I find solution,

in activity section, it response YouTube home page feed, but that's not sorted.

Comment: According to the documentation, you can specify exactly one of these parameters (channelId, id , mine, mySubscribers). Thats why you are getting "incompatibleParameters" error.

Comment: Saumini, sorry, I ask wrong question. I wonder to get subscription video feed, not subscription list. this can work?

Comment: To my knowledge YouTube v3 API doesn't support retrieving subscription video feed.

Comment: really? so I should use API v2 to complete?